# Use global variable and formula field vs get record in flow builder?

Tags: visual-workflow, bestpractice

I have a question on what is best practice / more efficient way of building a flow.  I need to get ~ 3 current running user fields for decisions in a flow.  Currently, I'm just using formula fields and referencing the global user variable, e.g.

```
TEXT({!$User.Group_Member__c})
```

However, I need access a new user custom field, and I'm wondering if it is more resource efficient to just get the entire user record (or the ~5 fields I need) with a record variable.  I tend to need user fields a lot in my flows so I'm curious which method to use moving forward.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the formulas. The Fast Lookup element consumes a SOQL query (limit 100 per transaction), but the $User formula does not; the user record fields are loaded when the flow starts automatically. Using $User is more efficient in every way. Of course, if you need someone that's not the running user, Fast Lookup is what you'd need then.